# Byobu-tmux vi-copy doesn't work after system upgrade (KDE Neon)

Tags: tmux, byobu

I have in my ~/.byobu/.tmux.conf

```
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection                                                                                                                                 
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
```

so normally I could enter in copy mode by:

Prefix + [

then I could use vi commands to navigate and enter vi select mode by 'v'
yank the selection by 'y'

after that I could put/paste in the terminal by:

Prefix + ]

Now after a system upgrade of KDE Neon (v - begin-selection) doesn't work anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Because of newer Tmux version I had to change my config:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection                                                                                                                 
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection \; send-keys -X cancel
```

Thanks to 'rushiagr' (http://www.rushiagr.com/blog/2016/06/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting-ubuntu)