# Byobu with screen backend: Connect copy buffer to system clipboard

Tags: screen, clipboard, byobu, xclip

I'm using [Byobu](https://www.byobu.org/) with the `screen` backend. (Because the default `tmux` backend causes some bug in SSH.)

When I use Byobu's copy feature to mark text with the keyboard and copy it into the buffer, I want that text to be copied to the system clipboard, so I could paste it in other applications.

You can do this [easily](http://www.rushiagr.com/blog/2016/06/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting-ubuntu/) under the tmux backend, and there are some [Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098068/byobu-tmux-vi-copy-doesnt-work-after-system-upgrade-kde-neon) about that, but I want to have the same functionality when using Byobu with the `screen` backend. **Is that possible? How?**